# extract coefficient of x^k from Ryacas calculated expression

Tags: r, yacas

[image]

I got a Ryacas expression like this, and I want to extract the coefficient of x^4,11. How should I write the code to get this, thanks.

Comment: Please provide code in a reproducible and copy&paste-able format. Screenshots of code/data are never a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
x <- Sym("x")
P <- (x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3)
Expand(P)
# expression(x^3 + 6 * x^2 + 11 * x + 6)
# coefficient of x^2:
yacas("Coef((x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3), x, 2)")
# expression(6)
# or:
yacas(paste0("Coef(", P, ",x , 2)"))
# expression(6)
```

---

## EDIT 2020-02

Updated for the new version of `Ryacas`:

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- ysym("x")
yac_assign((x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3), "P")
### expand the polynomial
yac_str("Expand(P)")
# [1] "x^3+6*x^2+11*x+6"
### extract coefficient of x^2:
yac_str("Coef(P, x, 2)")
# [1] "6"
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer , although I already solved this problem by extract from character string,but I think your way is more simple and beautiful.